# Check if website is loading will all its resources in C# .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

My goal is to make a request to web page which consists video player. The link looks like this:

*mywebsite*/620x439/9122600a

but if you want to have better resolution you have to pass an argument with it, so the link looks like this:

*mywebsite*/620x439/9122600a?wersja=720p

The problem is, that my program won't know if video from this link have better resolution, it have to figure it out itself. I had an idea to make a request to this URI and check the server response. I do it this way:

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri(videoPageURLHD);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
      //do something                  
}
else
{
      //do something else                  
}
```

The problem is, that no matter if video file with resolution exists or not, server always responds with HTTP 200, despite in debug console in web browser I can see that it failed to load resource -> [image: Browser console response]

The question is: is it possible to get this info about failing to load resource using request/Webclient/whatever? As an output I need simple true/false answer to question if this video have better resolution or not.

Comment: You can only use a real browser, such as headless Chrome to achieve this. `HttpWebRequest` only grabs the outer page, which definitely would be 200.

Comment: I'm writing kind of downloader for this page (cda.pl) and I want my program to detect automatically if better quality of video than the standard one is available. For now it can for example download all videos from given folder so checking by my self if all of the videos have better quality available would be pointless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to get this info about failing to load resource using
>   request/Webclient

No. `HttpRequest` and `WebClient` only loads the html, nothing else. They don't render the page, validate the html syntax, let alone loading JavaScript and Video.

You are getting a 200 is because the html download was successful. You could however try to figure out the Url for the video and try to download it using `WebClient` if its not blocked by the server.